# How to obtain a level map from points?

Tags: qgis, point

I have a points dataset (X and Y values) with different values (from 0 to 5). I wish to obtain a map like that:

[image]

I need the points with a value of 5 to be represented with the darkest color, the point with a value of 4 with a lighter color, etc.

How can I do that with QGIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I first had another focus on the answer, the styling described below should not be necessary for the final result.

As you already stated in the comment, Kriging or any other interpolation method like Spline, IDW, etc. can create the interpolated map from your given points.

These algorithms can be used from the Processing Toolbox (open via Processing -> Toolbox) within QGIS.

There are also a couple of tutorials on youtube on how to use these algorithms, e.g. a [kriging example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0OpMp9r6frs).

**Initial answer:**

Right-click on your point layer and choose "Properties". In the new window go to "Symbology" and change the symbology type to "Categorized". Choose the column where you values are saved, choose a color ramp (e.g. white-to-black) and click "Classify".

Now your symbology depends on the value of each point and should look like that:

[image: categorized symbology example]

Comment: Thank you ! And after this step, what tool should I use ? Interpolation ? I have seen some tuto where they use kringin algorithm but I don't know how to use it..

Comment: I updated the answer with a basic description of the workflow. Do you just don't find the Kriging algorithm in QGIS? Or are you stuck with some specific problems when using the algorithm with your data. If so, please add some details regarding these problems to your question.

Comment: No it is perfect thank you very much for your help !

Comment: @Vincent Quiquempois  you should accept the answer (checkmark), if tallistroans answer did solve your problem